# Using Identity Server v3 for SSO without OWIN in asp.net application

Tags: single-sign-on

I want to implement SSO using Thinktecture Identity Server V3. The applications the I want to use this SSO are asp.net MVC apps. I was going through samples provided on the thinktecture wiki and am able to see two approaches:

1- Resource owner(providing credentials through application and calling Identity server using OAuth2Client Apis)
2- Using Owin middleware(Startup class) to call the Identity server.

In my case I wanted to calling Identity server login, but without using Owin. Do you any hints/sample on how to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the Microsoft OpenId Connect middleware (and as a result OWIN) in your clients, you could initiate the login flow yourself by redirecting the user to the authorize endpoint.

Authorize endpoint: http://thinktecture.github.io/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3.Documentation/docs/endpoints/authorization.html

They guys behind IdentityServer have a client example showing some of the concepts if you want to handle it all yourself:

https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3.Samples/blob/master/source/Clients/MvcFormPostClient/Controllers/AccountController.cs